# How is tab completion implemented for linux commands?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I've noticed that sometimes commands can be tab completed.

e.g. the xm command in xen.

you type xm[space][tab] and it prints out the valid options
which are:

```
addlabel        destroy         info            network-attach  resume          sysrq           vnet-delete
block-attach    dmesg           labels          network-detach  rmlabel         top             vnet-list
block-detach    domid           list            network-list    save            trigger         vtpm-list
block-list      domname         loadpolicy      new             sched-credit    unpause         
cfgbootpolicy   dry-run         log             pause           sched-sedf      uptime          
console         dump-core       makepolicy      reboot          serve           vcpu-list       
create          dumppolicy      mem-max         rename          shutdown        vcpu-pin        
debug-keys      getlabel        mem-set         resources       start           vcpu-set        
delete          help            migrate         restore         suspend         vnet-create
```

That's pretty slick!

How can I implement my own tab command completion in Linux?

Comment: This is done by the shell. What shell are you asking about? (I'm guessing bash, since it's default in most distros now.)

Comment: yes bash, and I've now tagged my question with bash. Is it some kind of wrapper script?

Comment: Looks like a dupicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570795/how-does-bash-tab-completion-work

Comment: Thanks @Corey Farwell, I didn't realize it was part of bash so the other question you link to provides me the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, but the general idea is that you register something with the either the `compgen` or `complete` builtin. They're [both documented in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins). The previous section documents the general topic of [programmable completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion), going through how completion attempts are processed.

For a whole ton of examples, see `/etc/bash_completion`, which provides all the default completion that comes with bash (beyond the totally built-in stuff like filename completion). For even more examples, see anything in `/etc/bash_completion.d`; those are automatically sourced by `/etc/bash_completion` as a way of extending the default completion.

Answer (score 1):

This is done via the shell through the use of the [GNU Readline library](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html) in the case of `bash`

Answer (score 1):

bash's smart completion is handled by a series of scripted bash functions. On Debian, probably Ubuntu, and maybe other Linux distributions, you can find your system's installed completions in `/etc/bash_completion.d`.

The official documentation on this mechanism is at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion

Answer (score -1):

See this:

- [How does bash tab completion work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570795/how-does-bash-tab-completion-work)

and this:

- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316

Comment: When half of your answer is a link to another question, that's usually a sign you should be voting to close as a duplicate, not posting an answer. (If you feel the second link is helpful, you can contribute it somewhere on that question.)

Comment: @Jefromi Fair enough - I thought they were not the same, given the other question doesn't contain the request to actually do the completion, just how it works part. The second link is what I think refers to the second part.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an *exact* duplicate, but I think it's close enough; it points you in the right direction, especially given that the answer mentions /etc/bash_completion, where you can find a zillion examples. If you want to add an answer to the other question focusing more on implementing actual completion stuff I think that'd be valuable.

Comment: @Jefromi You've conviced me! :)