# Java main class autocomplete

Tags: java, shell, command-line, autocomplete

If I'm trying to run a java program and I don't know the exact name of the Main class, is there any way to use tab completion to figure it out?

```
java -cp stackoverflow.jar org.<tab>
stackoverflow serverfault stackexchange

java -cp stackoverflow.jjar org.stackoverflow.<tab>
Main IntegrationTest QuestionAnswerConsole
```

Something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you are asking how to configure shell autocompetion  to support java. It is possible. Take a look on this discussion: [How does bash tab completion work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570795/how-does-bash-tab-completion-work)

I have to say that this is a good idea not only for discovering the main class but also to complete other command line options and a class path. I'd be glad to use such script if you develop it. Good luck.

EDIT

At least on my Ubuntu file `less /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/java` exists and therefore some completion should work. You are always welcome to improve the script.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the Tab Completion that you are talking about is to use a shell that is "Java aware" or a shell script that provides this feature for the `java` command. `git` has a similar feature, so I don't think it's completely impossible.

**Edit:**

According to [this question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/467768/bash-filename-tab-completion), it is possible to create an autocompletion script for the bash shell. Since the question on SU is slightly different than what you are asking, I don't see a lot of specific details that relate to this question. However, it looks like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers suggest you solutions but as a sidenote, you don't need it if you provide maintainer of the jar file provides a manifest file with path `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Then `java` automatically extracts main class from the manifest and you can run it this way:

`java -jar stackoverflow.jar`

Comment: Only, if there is a manifest entry for Java main class. Otherwise we should find out by Java decompiler or ask the provider for the instructions to execute.

Comment: There could be multiple main methods in a jar as well.

Comment: If we find more main methods by decompiling then we should find out the right class to use from Provider

Comment: @ArtemShnayder True. However, AFAIK, there can only be one `Main-Class` entry in the JAR's manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any easy way to get the autocompletion of classes names if they are hidden in a jar file.

On the other hand, you can add a Manifest to your jar to make it auto-executable (ie., you just have to run `java -cp ... -jar stackoverflow.jar`) !

In the jar archive, add a `META-INF` folder, and inside that folder, create a `MANIFEST.MF` file that reads :

```
Main-Class: org.stackoverflow.Main
```

(or whatever your main class really is).

Here is some documentation : [Setting an application's Entrypoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)