# How to browse directories while issuing a mv command?

Tags: bash, command-line, directory, mv

Currently, I'm trying to move a file that I mistakenly saved to my home directory, and to do that I'm using a mv command. However, after I typed out the first part of my mv command:

`mv lab2prog.c 111/lab/...`

I forgot what directory I wanted to move the file in. Usually, I would just backspace the command and go directory exploring, but I recall a co-worker of mine browsing the directories of his system while issuing the command without having to delete the already typed command.

Is there a way to do that, or am I just imagining things...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>tab</kbd> twice to get a list of possible autocompletions in each step. This means you can also see a list of paths starting with, e.g., `do` by issuing: <kbd>mv lab2prog.c 111/lab/do</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your shell, most shells will have completion when you hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. The easiest way to determine the shell you are running is to `echo $SHELL`.

Typically you will be using bash (`/bin/bash`), this answer: [How does bash tab completion work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570795/how-does-bash-tab-completion-work) answer gives you some more information about your options for auto-completion. It can be quite sophisticated where the command is taken into account: that is when you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> you get a sensible completion. Debian also have a brief introduction for bash:

[An introduction to bash completion: part 1](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1)

Answer (score 0):

you can press tab , it will display all possible dirs

Answer (score 0):

I usually can just press the tab key to autocomplete with possible paths, though this may give you a very large output.