# How to get bash tab completions for your own project with gflags?

Tags: c++, bash, autocomplete, gflags

I've just starting using [gflags](https://gflags.github.io/gflags/) for a couple of C++ projects I'm working on. I find that the --help returns a large amount of flags, and I'm currently using `myapp --help | less` to find the flags I'm looking for. I would love to have tab completion for this.

Tonight I discovered the [files for completion](https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/master/src/gflags_completions.sh) in the git repository of glags. And that the command `gflags_completions.sh` has been installed in my bash environment with gflags.

**Questions**

1. Is there any documentation for gflags_completion.sh and how to use it? **Yes**, [gflags_completions.h.in](https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/master/src/gflags_completions.h.in)
2. How do I use the gflags_completion.sh script to make a completion entry for my own applications? *(See answer below)*

**Minimal example: myapp.cc**

To compile this file, run `g++ -o myapp myapp.cc -lgflags`.

```
/** GFlags test app for tab completion.
 *  License: Creative Commons 4.0 Attribution
 *  Compile with:
 *  g++ -o myapp myapp.cc -lgflags 
 */
#include <gflags/gflags.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  google::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);
  return 0;
}
```

**What I believe should have worked**

After reading up a bit on the [complete](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins) command, I believe this should work, but I do not succeed.

```
$ complete -o nospace -C \
  '/usr/local/bin/gflags_completions.sh --tab_completion_columns $COLUMNS' \
  time env myapp
$ ./myapp -[TAB]
```

Related question: [How does bash tab completion work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570795/how-does-bash-tab-completion-work)

Comment: "it's probably some very similar questions on bash auto-completions here on SO" -- if you didn't actually search for duplicates before you posted the question, you should do that yourself and then mark the question as a duplicate yourself, if you feel that its worth having this question. instead of asking others to find the duplicated info for you.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for pointing this out - and that the language I used is pretty much a provocation. I realize that now :) I have looked through the duplicate candidates, and there is nothing else on gflags_completions AFAIK. I believe we can justify having this question as soon as we get a couple of edits in.

Comment: ok, just checking :)

Comment: Can you have a look again @ChrisBeck, and see if you think this makes more sense?

Comment: it looks like a good question, I don't know the answer but you have my upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, with some help from a friend i found the file [gflags_completions.h.in](https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/master/src/gflags_completions.h.in) where the documentation for this feature is. I have pasted a part of the header file in the end of this answer.

What was missing from my question above, is the incude statement for `gflags_completions.h`.

**Minimal working example: myapp.cc**

```
/** GFlags test app for tab completion.
 *  License: Creative Commons 4.0 Attribution
 *  Compile with:  g++ -o myapp myapp.cc -lgflags
 */
#include <gflags/gflags.h>
#include <gflags/gflags_completions.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);
  return 0;
}
```

**To test this, go through these steps in a bash terminal:**

```
$ g++ -o myapp myapp.cc -lgflags      # Compile the example.
$ which gflags_completions.sh         # Check the path of gflags_compl...
/usr/local/bin/gflags_completions.sh  # I use this path below.
# Tell bash to use autocomplete for myapp.
$ complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -C \
'/usr/local/bin/gflags_completions.sh --tab_completion_columns $COLUMNS'\
time env myapp
```

**The resulting output is:**

```
$ ./myapp -[TAB]
~
-----------------
--flagfile [''] load flags from file
--fromenv [''] set flags from the environment [use 'export FLAGS_f'...
--help [false] show help on all flags [tip: all flags can have two ...
--helpfull [false] show help on all flags -- same as -help
--helpmatch [''] show help on modules whose name contains the speci...
--helpon [''] show help on the modules named by this flag value
--helppackage [false] show help on all modules in the main package
--helpshort [false] show help on only the main module for this program
--helpxml [false] produce an xml version of help
-* Other flags *-
--tab_completion_columns [80] Number of columns to use in output fo...
--tab_completion_word [''] If non-empty, HandleCommandLineCompletio...
--tryfromenv [''] set flags from the environment if present
--undefok [''] comma-separated list of flag names that it is okay t...
--version [false] show version and build info and exit
```

**Snipplet from [gflags_completions.h.in](https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/master/src/gflags_completions.h.in)**:

> **How to have bash accept completions from a binary:**
>
> Bash requires that it be informed about each command that programmatic
>   completion should be enabled for.  Example addition to a .bashrc
>   file would be (your path to gflags_completions.sh file may differ):
>
> ```
> $ complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -C                            \
>   '/home/build/eng/bash/bash_completions.sh --tab_completion_columns $COLUMNS'\
>   time  env  binary_name  another_binary  [...]
> ```
>
> This would allow the following to work:
>
> ```
> $ /path/to/binary_name --vmodule<TAB>
> ```
>
> Or:
>
> ```
> $ ./bin/path/another_binary --gfs_u<TAB>
> ```
>
> (etc)
>
> Sadly, it appears that bash gives no easy way to force this behavior
>   for         all commands.  That's where the "time" in the above
>   example comes in.            If you haven't specifically added a
>   command to the list of completion            supported commands, you
>   can still get completions by prefixing the               entire
>   command with "env".
>
> ```
> $ env /some/brand/new/binary --vmod<TAB>
> ```
>
> Assuming that "binary" is a newly compiled binary, this should still
>   produce the expected completion output.