# How can I inject symbols for autocompletion into R in a specific context?

Tags: r, autocomplete

A couple of years ago, I hacked together a system that uses lazy evaluation to allow users to perform filter operations based on field names being returned by an API. This allows users to write R code that gets translated to API calls, but field names are treated as "variable names". For example:

```
files() %>% filter(~ file_id == "XYZ" & cases.case_id %in% c("a", "b"))
```

The `file_id` and `cases.case_id` are not R variables but are injected into the formula environment at evaluation. What I am looking for is a way to do autocomplete using these names as users type. The field names are known *a priori* given the context of `files()` and `filter`.

FYI, the package that implements this is the Bioconductor [GenomicDataCommons package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/GenomicDataCommons). Some of the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/Bioconductor/GenomicDataCommons/blob/master/R/filters.R#L9-L72).

Edit: To clarify and simplify even further, if I have a character vector of tokens, how can I have R do tab completion on those tokens in a given context (in this case, a formula context)?

Comment: are you looking for a way to receive inputs from users to an endpoint defined by you and returning values which essentially are filenames which the user could click upon ? I imagine you could do that with any of the more resilient API infrastructures in R like ocpu, Rserve, or RestRServe. However, in general for autocomplete option, I think using sth like elasticsearch should be better.

Comment: Thanks, @deann. I'm interested in tab-completion at the R command-line, not really in an "app" for users. If I simplify even further, if I have a character vector of tokens, how can I have R do tab completion on those tokens in a given context (in this case, a formula context)?

Comment: if I correctly understand what you are aiming at, essentially you are trying to replicate the RStudio's tab competion but in a command-line environment? If that is the case I would start looking at bash completions script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570795/how-does-bash-tab-completion-work

Comment: Thanks again, @deann. That is the functionality that I am hoping to achieve. My understanding is that Rstudio has basically rewritten completion in their environment, so there might be a need to have more than one approach. Lots of new stuff to learn. : )